# Android Device Monitor dark theme

Tags: android-studio, ddms

I use Android Studio with dark theme. And i'd like Android Device Monitor to be dark as well.
In preferences->General->Appearance i found dropdown "Theme", but it is empty. Googling for ADM theme or DDMS theme didn't work. Is there any themes for this tool?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

No themes yet. Maybe sometime in the future. Feel free to file a feature request: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Tools%20feature%20request